# CSS Animation when Div is added in Vue v-for list

Tags: css, vue.js

I had a vue list like below:

```
<div v-for="item in items">
   <div class="animation">{{ item.name }}</div>
</div>
```

And my animation is

```
@keyframes loadingComment {
    0% {
        opacity: 0.6 !important;
    }
    99% {
        opacity: 0.6 !important;
    }
    100% {
        opacity: 1;
    }
}
```

However when I add an animation to to item it starts the animation whenever the page loads even tho there are 0 items inside the array. I want the animation to play when the item is added to the items array. Any ideas? I assumed this is how it would work as default?

Thanks,
Jamie

Comment: You can do this using <transition> elements. Have you tried using that?

Comment: Can you include more code? Like the rest of you template and the `animation` class which we can't see here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

first, you need to wrap your entire list section in a transition-group if you want to add animation to your list.  [Read more here](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/transitions.html)

```
<transition-group name="list">
  <div v-for="item in items" :key="item.id">
     <div class="animation">{{ item.name }}</div>
  </div>
</transition-group>
```

you need to specify a name for your transition. in that way you can control your animation style in CSS.`<transition-group name="list">`

If you only want to use fade animation you can use transitions for that. no need for keyframes.
something like this:

```
.list-enter-active, .list-leave-active {
  opacity: 1;
  transition: opacity .5s;
}
.list-enter, .list-leave-to /* .fade-leave-active below version 2.1.8 */ {
  opacity: 0;
}
```

but if you really want to use keyframes, in your example you can do something like this:

```
.list-enter-active, .list-leave-active {
   animation: loadingComment 0.5s ease-in-out forwards;
}
@keyframes loadingComment {
  0% {
    opacity: 0.6;
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
}
```

also, you can see the result in this jsfiddle link [jsfiddle demo](https://jsfiddle.net/Nakazaki/a2y8kj7h/31/)